# How to see which files are in packages in the package registry on GitLab using GitLab4J?

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

I've managed to get a connection to GitLab API working and I can see the available projects and their respective packages in the package registries. I'm having a problem understanding how to programatically see the files inside of a package, aka how to get the **filename.extension** in my URL:

.../projectID/packages/generic/packageName/packageVersion/**filename.extension**

Also, is there a smarter way of downloading the package files other than using URL and HttpURLConnection in Java?

I've managed to donwload files already with the hardcoded version of the URL (via curl and programatically), where I knew the name and the file extension beforehand. Since I won't have that option for the actual download, I expect that there is a way to generalize this, I just haven't found it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually quite simple, the documentation if pretty well written (I just missed it somehow) [package files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html#list-package-files)